# (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, app-router

In **Next JS** when use library see this error use

```
"use client"
```

When using a library in Next js version 13 or later that utilizes Interactivity and Browser APIs for client components, such as state, effects, event listeners, geolocation, or localStorage, the error can be resolved by including the 'use client' statement at the beginning of the file.